# Evaluating a recursive B-spline function

Tags: c++, spline

I want to write a function that computes a B-spline that takes a set of data values F which are located at corresponding support points x in an interval [a,b] and a degree k as an input and outputs the set of coefficients such that the spline exactly interpolates the points F.

My first question is: is there a software library out there that does that? I only found it for cubic splines, but not for any given degree k.

So I tried to implement it myself. My idea was that based on my support points x and my degree k, I need to construct a knot vector T. The approach is to choose my T such that I repeat the boundary values k+1 times, meaning t_0=..=t_k=a (same thing for the right boundary for b) and between that, choose t_{k+j+1} = x_j. This way, the knot vector entries would be the same values as the support points. With that information, I should be able to construct a system matrix B, such that B(i)(j) = N_{i,k}(x_j), where N is the B-spline basis function evaluated with the cox-de-boor formula. With this system matrix constructed, I should be able to compute Bc=F and obtain values for c such that my spline interpolates the function values F. However, my implementation sadly fails so far, even in constructing the system matrix. The code is the following:

```
    double eval_recurs(int i, double x, const int p, const double* t){
       double A,N;
       if(p==0){
         if (x>=t[i] && x<t[i+1]){
            return 1;
            
         }
         else{
            return 0;
         }
       } 
       else{
        if(t[i+p] != t[i]){
             A =(x- t[i])/(t[i+p]-t[i]);
            
        }
        else{
             A = 0; 
        }
        if(t[i+p+1] != t[i+1]){
             N= (t[i+p+1]-x)/(t[i+p+1]-t[i+1]);

        }
        else{
             N =0;
        }
        return A*eval_recurs(i,x,p-1,t) + N*eval_recurs(i+1,x,p-1,t);
       }  
    }
  int main() {
        const int a = 0;//left boundary 
        const int b = 1; // right boundary  
        const int k = 4; //degree
        const double F[] = {1,2,3,4,1,8,7,6};
        const int length = sizeof(F) / sizeof(F[0]);
        const int l = length -k;
        const int n = l + 2*k;
        const double h = (double)(b-a)/(k+l-1); //stepsize     
        double t[n]; //knot vector
        for(int i = 0;i<k;i++){
             t[i] = a; //k values on the left are equal knots
             t[n-1-i]=b; //k values on the right are equal knots
        }
      
        for(int i =1; i<l+1;i++){ 
            t[i+k-1]= a+ i*h; //equally spaced points in the middle
        }
        double B[k+l][k+l]; // system matrix
        for(int i = 0; i<k+l;i++){
           for(int j = 1; j<k+l-1; j++){         
             B[i][j] = eval_recurs(i,j*h,k,t);
           }
        }
    
    return 0;
 }
```

The result I get for my matrix B for the values shown in the code is the following:

0.000    0.125   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
0.000    0.514   0.056   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
0.000    0.319   0.444   0.042   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
0.000    0.042   0.472   0.614   0.225   0.044   0.003   0.000
0.000    0.000   0.028   0.324   0.518   0.280   0.051   0.000
0.000    0.000   0.000   0.020   0.242   0.463   0.273   0.000
0.000    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.016   0.201   0.476   0.000
-0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.012   0.198   0.000

The columns add up to 1 so it does not seem to be completely wrong if I transpose the matrix. However, the first and last columns are 0, so what am I missing here? Do I have too many degrees of freedom? If so, how can I get rid of them?

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?